# C++ integer array transforms and manipulation

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have an assignment to

- input an array,
- count its even numbers (positive and negative),
- calculate the sum of all even #
- and after the program has to out put a transformed array, where each even # is changed into a sum of all numbers that stand before it (** in the original array **) : `arr[i] = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;` -> `array[i] = 1, 1, 3, 6, 5, 15`

so here's how I tried it, but it works up to the 5th element after which it starts outputting some odd looking #s. What do i have to do???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int n, i, k = 0;
    int sum;
    int S = 0;
    cout << "What size array would you like:" << endl;
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    int* A = new int[n];
    sum = 0;
    cout << "Input elements: ";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> A[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] % 2 == 0) {
            k = k + 1;
            sum += A[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Ampount of even numbs: " << k << endl << endl;
    cout << "Sum of even numbs: " << sum << endl << endl;
    cout << "New array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (abs(A[i]) % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                S += A[j];
            }
            A[i] = S;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: did you use a debugger?

Comment: suggested reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: if you want help with debugging the code you need to inlcude input, output and expected output in the question.

Comment: @MaxLanghof VLAs in C++ -> bad. `new` -> bad. => VLAs == `new` (some kind of shortcut in my brain).

Comment: Tip: What is the value of `S` when you start inner loop? You can print it before entering this loop (or use a debugger).

Comment: Maybe for (int i=1; i<n; ++i){ if (even) S += A[i-1]; A[i] = S; }

Comment: you can do all of it in 1 loop

Comment: @MFnx how thought?

Comment: what happens if the first element is even? you set A[0] = 0?

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you said, C++ and "fun", so here is a more C++ way to skin this cat . .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;    

int main() {
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    const auto isEven = [](int x){return x%2==0;};
    const auto print = [](const int& n) { cout << " " << n; };

    cout << "Before: "; for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), print); cout << endl;
    cout << "Num Even: " << count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), isEven) << endl;
    cout << "Sum Even: " << accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, [isEven](auto acc, int e) { return acc + (isEven(e) ? e : 0); }) << endl;
    // I'm not guru enough for Jarod42s c++20 voodoo nor is IDEONE 
    int b=0;
    vector<int> v2;
    for (auto& x : v) {
        isEven(x) ? v2.push_back(b) : v2.push_back(x);
        b+=x;
    }
    cout << "Transformed: "; for_each(v2.begin(), v2.end(), print); cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Try here https://ideone.com/jDjoeB

Comment: `const auto a = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, [](auto acc, int e) { return acc + (isEven(e) ? e : 0); })`. And even with range-v3: `accumulate(v | views::filter(&isEven), 0)` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 `views::filter` looks awesome 

Comment: Nice. Output is not correct though: it should be Transformed:  1 1 3 6 5 15

Comment: @MFnx 1+1+3=5 the last time I checked 

Comment: Check his example. He sums the elements of the original array. Not the modified one.

Comment: @MFnx ahhh ok. Done

Answer (score 0):

In your second-last loop you are changing every even number to their predecessors sum and then still iterate again over all numbers in the array. That means you are summing the sums!
Either temporarily write the output to a new array, or better be smart and separately sum all numbers to the current point instead of re-looping once for every even number.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second loop to get `S`, you can do it in the first one. Also, don't forget deleting your array.

Design with pencil and paper before coding.

A solution to your problem could be something like this.

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr static size_t N = 10;

int main()
{  
    int* A = new int[N];

    /* fill array A */

    int sum(0), k(0), S(0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        S += A[i];
        if (A[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            ++k;
            sum += A[i];
            if (i == 0) // nothing before index 0
                A[i] = 0;
            else
                A[i] = S - A[i]; // here's the trick
        } 
    }

    delete[] A; // don't forget this!

    return 0;
}
```